# Show Locations in Google Search Results

Tags: seo, google-search

I have noticed some location specific sites have urls in Google search results showing up like this

[image]

Can anyone give insight into how Google determines to show these types of results, which are also separate links btw.

Comment: Note Google result is smart enough to allow 'North America', 'United States' and 'Colorado' to all be clickable and go to that specific content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a very long time this was achieved by

1. Adding good breadcrumbs  US > Colorado > Denver
2. Adding good url patters .com/us/co/denver

This was able to give Google enough information to give the search results similar or exactly the same as in the question screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Webmaster Tools and set your Geographic target.

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=62399

To set a geographic target:

1. On the Webmaster Tools Home page, click the site you want.
2. List item Under Site configuration, click Settings.
3. List item In the Geographic target section, select the option you want.

If you want to ensure that your site is not associated with any country or region, select Unlisted.

Hope it helps

Comment: this is not what I was asking, see the screen shot above.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood your question, see image [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bLv1v.png) one site doesn't have "United States" mentioned and other has it. This can be achieved from webmaster tools.

Can you please share the search query also for which you have the above results?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=running+maps+in+colorado&aq=f&oq=running+maps+in+colorado&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=running+maps+in+boulder&oq=running+maps+in+boulder&gs_l=serp.3..0i22l2.7590.8582.0.8663.7.7.0.0.0.0.98.526.7.7.0.les%3Bcqrwrth.1.0.0...1.1.tEMj64TNchE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=80ef5323c76d6b79&bpcl=35466521&biw=1226&bih=658

Comment: Check the link it might help http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334